# Update the worksheet of one excel sheet from another excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update the value of the cell of one Excel from another Excel automatically.
Suppose I have the first Excel name as"予備品.xlsm" and another as "予備品1.xlsm".
When I update the first row A1 of the first Excel with some value it must reflect in another Excel A1. The second Excel sheet is not opened and just want to update that excell.

```
Sub HelloCaller()
    Dim AllCellsRange As Range
    Set AllCellsRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Hello AllCellsRange
End Sub

Sub Hello(Target As Range)
   Dim secondWorkbookPath As String
   Dim secondWorkbook As Workbook
   Dim secondHelloSheet As Worksheet
' Specify the path to the second workbook
   secondWorkbookPath = "C:\Users\WS035\Desktop\連絡書_MACRO\予備品1.xlsm"

  Set secondWorkbook = Workbooks("予備品1.xlsm")
  On Error GoTo 0

  If secondWorkbook Is Nothing Then
    Set secondWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(secondWorkbookPath)
 End If

Set secondHelloSheet = secondWorkbook.Sheets("付属品1")
secondHelloSheet.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = Target.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HelloCaller()
    Dim AllCellsRange As Range
    Set AllCellsRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Hello AllCellsRange
End Sub

Sub Hello(Target As Range)
    Dim secondWorkbookPath As String
    Dim secondWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim secondHelloSheet As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Specify the path to the second workbook
    secondWorkbookPath = "C:\Users\WS035\Desktop\連絡書_MACRO\予備品1.xlsm"
    ' secondWorkbookPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Book2.xlsm" ' for testing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set secondWorkbook = Workbooks("予備品1.xlsm")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If secondWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        Set secondWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(secondWorkbookPath)
    End If
    
    Set secondHelloSheet = secondWorkbook.Sheets("付属品1") '
    ' Set secondHelloSheet = secondWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' for testing
    secondHelloSheet.Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value
    ' secondWorkbook.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry but this code doesnot work as expected. As this code only closes the second sheet if opened before or open the second if closed before but donot update the value to the cell in second sheet.

Comment: I thought you are going to update the first sheet. You can remove the code which closes the second sheet. I've updated the code.